# Compare old to new value at validation in LightSwitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Is there a possibility to compare the old value to the new one during validation.

Say you have a State on some object that is set to A and changed to B. This should only be allowed if the entity fulfills certain circumstances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can access the original values by drilling into the entity.Details.Properties.[propname].OriginalValue

Comment: Can't find "OriginalValue" property in LightSwitch 2013.
Any idea how to do this coparison in LS-2013?

Comment: Sorry, solved:
entity.Details.Properties.{propertyName}.OriginalValue;
I thought "propertyName" should be used as index value for Properties[] set.